# How to get size (metadata) of a message without fetch request in Kafka through SimpleConsumer?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using SimpleConsumer and trying to pull message size wise (bytes) using spark.

I am able to get earliest and latest offset using metadata request, but dont know how to get number of bytes in kafka (0.8.0).

I really dont want to use fetch request because want to check sufficient data then only will run spark job (not streaming) to perform action.

Comment: I got answer for this question. There is Api and spark conf have something from we can calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From metadata response cant get size, to get size need to download message which is meaningless.